# Connect to nodes on my network via ssh from Docker Container (defined in Jenkinsfile)

Tags: docker, jenkins, ssh, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to build a jenkins pipeline which automates some Chef InSpec test cases for infrastructure and compliance auditing. I'm using a groovy function to generate the stages with the actual test invocations. So far the basic setup works.

```
stage('test') {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'chef/inspec:latest'
            reuseNode true
        }
    }
    steps {
        script {
            parallel inspecTestStages(hosts, profiles)
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is connecting to nodes in my network. When I use `inspec exec $profile -t ssh://$host` (or `inspec exec profiles/infra-audit -t ssh://pi@prometheus` with vars replaced) the connection is not established.

I'm sure this is because the inspec container does not know any ssh keys. But I don't want to extend the image an add keys because these keys are private and sensible information which should not be of an image.

Does anyone know how to enable the inspec container to ssh into the nodes on my network? The host machine running this container has all ssh key information necessary. How can I mount these ssh information into the inspec container which I defined in my Jenkinsfile?

Comment: Do you have the option to use the `withCredentials` plugin?

Comment: yes I do ... But I would prefer to share the ssh settings with my host machine. I have a dedicated cert for every server on my network. Using credentials means I would have to add all of them to my jenkins ... If there is no good way to share ssh settings, I'm open to withCredentials. But I'd like to try sharing first ... Maybe it is enough to mount the $HOME/.ssh folder of my user into the container? Or find a way to have the container use the hosts ssh socket?

Comment: @MattSchuchard Got any ideas? Hope you can help me ...